# How to implement gaze and trigger with VR ONE in native iOS without Unity

Tags: scenekit, vrone

Is there a native iOS code sample with SceneKit that shows gaze and trigger interaction in an VR app (with VR One). Used **VR SceneKit** and **VR-iOS-Experiment**- so app is working fine - but with no menus.

But how do you implement a gaze and trigger menu (in iOS only - no Unity) as seen in some of VR apps on the app store or in VR One's sample apps.

Comment: We build an app from scratch with that: https://appsto.re/de/CuXA8.i the menu was not an easy task. Basically it's build from primitive geometries. The gaze is a simple sphere. The trigger is implemented with an NSTimer. Also have a look at hit testing to find the node you are looking at.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful.

So, menus are implemented at text on a plane,  then  gaze and trigger to fire an action.